# How do you write a test for an apex trigger with NPSP?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, npsp

I wrote this trigger

```
trigger UpdateScholarShareDate on Contact (before update){  
    for( Contact con : Trigger.New){
        Contact oldCon = Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id);
        if( oldCon.Scholar_Share_Email__c != con.Scholar_Share_Email__c ){
            con.Scholar_Share_Email_Date__c = System.today();             
        }
    }
}
```

here is the test code i have written but it will not let me insert any objects to test.

```
@isTest
private class  TestUpdateScholarShareDate {
    @isTest 
    static void testUpdateScholarShareDate(){
        //Account acc =  new Account(Name='acc1', RecordType= new RecordType(Name ='Household'));
        // insert acc;
        // Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'testUpdateScholarShareDate1', Account = acc );
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'testUpdateScholarShareDate1');
        insert c;
        Test.startTest();
        Contact con = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Scholar_Share_Email_Date__c,Scholar_Share_Email__c FROM Contact Where LastName = 'testUpdateScholarShareDate1'];
        con.Scholar_Share_Email__c = false;
        update con;
        Contact con1 = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Scholar_Share_Email_Date__c,Scholar_Share_Email__c FROM Contact Where LastName = 'testUpdateScholarShareDate1'];
        con1.Scholar_Share_Email__c = true;
        update con1;
        Contact con2 = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName,Scholar_Share_Email_Date__c,Scholar_Share_Email__c FROM Contact Where LastName = 'testUpdateScholarShareDate1'];
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(con2.Scholar_Share_Email_Date__c , System.today());
        delete acc;
        delete c;
    }
}
```

I either get get this error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, npsp.TDTM_Contact: execution of BeforeInsert
>   caused by: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Class.npsp.ACCT_IndividualAccounts_TDTM.insertContactAccount: line 568, column 1
>   Class.npsp.ACCT_IndividualAccounts_TDTM.run: line 288, column 1
>   Class.npsp.TDTM_TriggerHandler.runClass: line 169, column 1
>   Class.npsp.TDTM_TriggerHandler.run: line 101, column 1
>   Trigger.npsp.TDTM_Contact: line 34, column 1: Expected: null, Actual: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 012j0000000KvvPAAS: [RecordTypeId]
>
> Class.npsp.TDTM_TriggerHandler.run: line 139, column 1
>   Trigger.npsp.TDTM_Contact: line 34, column 1: []

As you can see i added an account object previously and it didn't let me insert anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Consider enhancing your test code by inserting a user record at test data setup and assigning it a user profile that is allowed to use the npsp record types, per your org config.

Then, enclose the testing runtime code inside a runAs context. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm for details on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! that sis not fix the issue though.

Comment: Invalid cross reference error tells us that the user profile of running user does not have access to the correct record types. If you have implemented a system.runas user then worth checking that users profile permissions